# Where is the `#git150#.git` database in MySQL coming from?

Tags: mysql

Why is this DB appearing and making all sorts of problems? I have never consciously created it. Cannot delete it either.

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is a .git folder in /var/lib/mysql. Delete it or move it somewhere else, and it will be fixed.